# 'std::thread::thread': no overloaded function takes 7 arguments

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio 2012 and the above error popups. My code is correct but seems like the compiler is limited to 7 arguments. What can I do If I want to pass 7 arguments?

I can pass a struct but better not change my code if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VS2012 does not fully support variadic templates. Also see this Blogpost: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

You can set the maximum number of arguments as high as 10 by defining this Macro `_VARIADIC_MAX`.

So just do something like `#define _VARIADIC_MAX 10`.

The default values is 5, 2 standard argument + 5 variadic ones for std::thread. Overall you can pass as much as 12 parameters by settings the value above.

Comment: Is there a drawback if I increase the value? Also, is this fixed in VS2013?

Comment: @Luka: Compile time is increased. I imagine the compiler uses some trickery with some predefined macros to get things to work. VS2013 fully supports variadic templates.

Comment: @Luka: No problem. See this link for the C++11 features supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: The drawback is that VS'es macro magic has to be applied ten times instead of 5. It emulates the variadics by providing overloads with 1..N arguments by defining some macro constants including a macro header N times.

Comment: What do you mean they don't "support" it?